# PHP get json array key position

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

How can I get all the positions in the array `results`where the key `registration_id` exists ?

```
  $json_raw = '{"multicast_id":6446899316497614986,
                     "success":5,
                     "failure":1,
                     "canonical_ids":3,
                     "results":[
                             {"registration_id":"APA91bEgLFvrc0lnXqX3C1euQohdHrv_wbxtGP86ezRzGWEVMQPpJjw1GMhGzfkI8Q34TU1KRts2j_-7CyU4ce6MlX5DB3umpXDGl-Ebmg53b44UKga79ee9Sal6gT_9rP3KIz9pDEUk2JVJsQmxiWXWoIfrYEAmFg",
                               "message_id":"0:1396175384218906%50b5570df9fd7ecd"
                             },
                             {"registration_id":"APA91bEgLFvrc0lnXqX3C1euQohdHrv_wbxtGP86ezRzGWEVMQPpJjw1GMhGzfkI8Q34TU1KRts2j_-7CyU4ce6MlX5DB3umpXDGl-Ebmg53b44UKga79ee9Sal6gT_9rP3KIz9pDEUk2JVJsQmxiWXWoIfrYEAmFg",
                              "message_id":"0:1396175384218155%50b5570df9fd7ecd"
                             },
                             {"registration_id":"APA91bEgLFvrc0lnXqX3C1euQohdHrv_wbxtGP86ezRzGWEVMQPpJjw1GMhGzfkI8Q34TU1KRts2j_-7CyU4ce6MlX5DB3umpXDGl-Ebmg53b44UKga79ee9Sal6gT_9rP3KIz9pDEUk2JVJsQmxiWXWoIfrYEAmFg",
                              "message_id":"0:1396175384219100%50b5570df9fd7ecd"
                             },
                             {"message_id":"0:1396175384218718%b91f4d1ff9fd7ecd"
                             },
                             {"message_id":"0:1396175384219927%50b5570df9fd7ecd"
                             },
                             {"error":"InvalidRegistration"
                             }]
                       }';
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/json_decode) for this.

```
$data = json_decode($json_raw, TRUE);
foreach ($data['results'] as $key=>$result) {
    if (array_key_exists('registration_id', $result)) {
       //use now via $data['results'][$key] or simply $result
    }
}
```

Or if you want to only keep the ones where `registration_id` exists, use [`array_filter()`](http://www.php.net/array_filter):

```
function registrationIdExists($result) {
    return array_key_exists('registration_id', $result);
}

$data = json_decode($json_raw, TRUE);
$data['results'] = array_filter($data['results'], "registrationIdExists");
```

Comment: I'd suggest user `array_key_exists` instead of `isSet`  as the latter would return `false` if the key exists but its value is `null` - http://it2.php.net/array_key_exists

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, but i need to get the position in the complete results array of registration_id and not the value of this key